# Collect data from twitter in json format and for particular time frame

Tags: python, json, time

This code only stream data. I want to pull data for a 3 days time frame.

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

# will pass key and token
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

class TweetsListener( StreamListener ):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open('name.json', 'a') as f:
                f.write(data)
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True

twitter_stream = Stream( auth, TweetsListener() ) 
twitter_stream.filter( track=['XX'] )
```

Comment: You want to extract data of previous 3 days or the next 3 days, as far as stream is concerned, you can only access future data with the streaming API.

Comment: i want to collect previous 3 days data from twitter in json format. Can you help me out !

Answer (score 0):

You are using Twitter Streaming API which is used to capture future tweets with given criteria (`on_data` is called when a tweet with given search terms is posted). You need to use Twitter REST APIs to search previous data. See [tweepy.Search()](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.2.0/api.html#API.search)

> Parameters:
>
> q – the search query string
>
> since_id – Returns only
> statuses with an ID greater than (that is, more recent than) the
> specified ID.

Comment: Can you change this code. which can save in json format. Instaed of csv.

Comment: auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('X', 'X')
auth.set_access_token('X', 'X')

api = tweepy.API(auth)
# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, 
                    q="google", 
                    since="2014-02-14", 
                    until="2014-02-15", 
                    lang="en").items():
    #Write a row to the csv file/ I use encode utf-8
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
    print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
csvFile.close()

Comment: You can use code from your original question for that, from `on_data` method just change `f.write(data)` with `f.write(json.dumps(data))`. You will have to `import json` though.